# New features in java 7

Tags: java-7, java

What new features in java 7 is going to be implemented?
And what are they doing now?

Comment: [Full final list of language changes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html#javase7)

Answer (score 216):

### Java SE 7 [Features and Enhancements](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html) from JDK 7 Release Notes

This is the Java 7 new features summary from the [OpenJDK 7 features page](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/):

> ```
> vm  JSR 292: Support for dynamically-typed languages (InvokeDynamic)
>         Strict class-file checking
> lang    JSR 334: Small language enhancements (Project Coin)
> core    Upgrade class-loader architecture
>         Method to close a URLClassLoader
>         Concurrency and collections updates (jsr166y)
> i18n    Unicode 6.0
>         Locale enhancement
>         Separate user locale and user-interface locale
> ionet   JSR 203: More new I/O APIs for the Java platform (NIO.2)
>         NIO.2 filesystem provider for zip/jar archives
>         SCTP (Stream Control Transmission Protocol)
>         SDP (Sockets Direct Protocol)
>         Use the Windows Vista IPv6 stack
>         TLS 1.2
> sec     Elliptic-curve cryptography (ECC)
> jdbc    JDBC 4.1
> client  XRender pipeline for Java 2D
>         Create new platform APIs for 6u10 graphics features
>         Nimbus look-and-feel for Swing
>         Swing JLayer component
>         Gervill sound synthesizer [NEW]
> web     Update the XML stack
> mgmt    Enhanced MBeans [UPDATED]
> ```

### Code examples for new features in Java 1.7

#### Try-with-resources statement

this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
try {
   return br.readLine();
} finally {
   br.close();
}
```

becomes:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)) {
   return br.readLine();
}
```

You can declare more than one resource to close:

```
try (
   InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest))
{
 // code
}
```

#### Underscores in numeric literals

```
int one_million = 1_000_000;
```

#### Strings in switch

```
String s = ...
switch(s) {
 case "quux":
    processQuux(s);
    // fall-through

  case "foo":
  case "bar":
    processFooOrBar(s);
    break;

  case "baz":
     processBaz(s);
    // fall-through

  default:
    processDefault(s);
    break;
}
```

#### Binary literals

```
int binary = 0b1001_1001;
```

#### Improved Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

becomes:

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<>();
```

#### Multiple exception catching

this:

```
} catch (FirstException ex) {
     logger.error(ex);
     throw ex;
} catch (SecondException ex) {
     logger.error(ex);
     throw ex;
}
```

becomes:

```
} catch (FirstException | SecondException ex) {
     logger.error(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

#### SafeVarargs

this:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "varargs"})
public static void printAll(List<String>... lists){
    for(List<String> list : lists){
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

becomes:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static void printAll(List<String>... lists){
    for(List<String> list : lists){
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Code for the hard to find code examples. Can you add more?

Comment: The improved type inference seems to be a sad copy from C# with a weird change where a reference is typed, but the object is not?? What comedy!

Comment: @Zasz, yes sure, it is in continuous improvement

Comment: So question is to OP, what's your opinion? Are these enhancements just on productivity side, or they can really improve performance of programs? If no bytecode changes, can new language enhancements be used with bytecode marked as 1.5?

Comment: Although not a language improvement, there is the new `Objects` class, with static methods to avoid having to check for null refereces. Example: `if (obj != null && obj.equals(anotherObj))` becomes `if (Objects.equals(obj, anotherObj))`

Comment: really appreciated the effort, +1

Answer (score 13):

### New Feature of Java Standard Edition (JSE 7)

1. **Decorate Components with the JLayer Class:**

   The JLayer class is a flexible and powerful decorator for Swing components. The JLayer class in Java SE 7 is similar in spirit to the JxLayer project project at java.net. The JLayer class was initially based on the JXLayer project, but its API evolved separately.
2. **Strings in switch Statement**:

   In the JDK 7 , we can use a String object in the expression of a switch statement. The Java compiler generates generally more efficient bytecode from switch statements that use String objects than from chained if-then-else statements.
3. **Type Inference for Generic Instance:**

   We can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters (<>) as long as the compiler can infer the type arguments from the context. This pair of angle brackets is informally called the diamond.
   Java SE 7 supports limited type inference for generic instance creation; you can only use type inference if the parameterized type of the constructor is obvious from the context. For example, the following example does not compile:

   ```
   List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
   l.add("A");
   l.addAll(new ArrayList<>());
   ```

   In comparison, the following example compiles:

   ```
   List<? extends String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
   l.addAll(list2);
   ```
4. **Catching Multiple Exception Types and Rethrowing Exceptions with Improved Type Checking:**

   In Java SE 7 and later, a single catch block can handle more than one type of exception. This feature can reduce code duplication. Consider the following code, which contains duplicate code in each of the catch blocks:

   ```
   catch (IOException e) {
       logger.log(e);
       throw e;
   }
   catch (SQLException e) {
       logger.log(e);
       throw e;
   }
   ```

   In releases prior to Java SE 7, it is difficult to create a common method to eliminate the duplicated code because the variable e has different types.
   The following example, which is valid in Java SE 7 and later, eliminates the duplicated code:

   ```
   catch (IOException|SQLException e) {
       logger.log(e);
       throw e;
   }
   ```

   The catch clause specifies the types of exceptions that the block can handle, and each exception type is separated with a vertical bar (|).
5. **The java.nio.file package**

   The `java.nio.file` package and its related package, java.nio.file.attribute, provide comprehensive support for file I/O and for accessing the file system. A zip file system provider is also available in JDK 7.

Source: http://ohmjavaclasses.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 6):

[**Java Programming Language Enhancements @ Java7**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html)

1. [Binary Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10961101/1697099)
2. [Strings in switch Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10240598/1697099)
3. [Try with Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739460/1697099) ([How it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26366568/1697099)) or ARM ([Automatic Resource Management](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2011/09/arm-automatic-resource-management-in.html))
4. [Multiple Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495968/1697099)
5. [Suppressed Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)
6. [underscore in literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6212642/1697099)
7. [Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation using Diamond Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14909875/1697099)
8. [Improved Compiler Warnings and Errors When Using Non-Reifiable Formal Parameters with Varargs Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/non-reifiable-varargs.html)

[Official reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html)
[Official reference with java8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html)
[wiki reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7_.28July_28.2C_2011.29)

Comment: To the point! Top ten google search results for "**Java features**" returns the (useless) list: `Simple, Object-Oriented, Portable, Platform independent, Secured...`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what John Skeet said, here's an [overview of the Java 7 project](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/). It includes a list and description of the features.

Note: JDK 7 was released on July 28, 2011, so you should now go to the official [java SE site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: FYI, this is a good presentation but pretty old and somewhat out of date.

Comment: I got an error page in Hebrew when I tried this link - is there a more up to date copy anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

**Language changes**:

```
-Project Coin (small changes)
-switch on Strings
-try-with-resources
-diamond operator
```

**Library changes**:

```
-new abstracted file-system API (NIO.2) (with support for virtual filesystems)
-improved concurrency libraries
-elliptic curve encryption
-more incremental upgrades
```

**Platform changes**:

```
-support for dynamic languages
```

Below is the link explaining the newly added features of JAVA 7 , the explanation is crystal clear with the possible small examples for each features :

http://radar.oreilly.com/2011/09/java7-features.html

Answer (score 0):

> Using Diamond(<>) operator for generic instance creation

```
Map<String, List<Trade>> trades = new TreeMap <> ();
```

> Using strings in switch statements

```
String status=  “something”;
   switch(statue){
     case1: 
     case2: 
     default:
    }
```

> Underscore in numeric literals

int val 12_15;
long phoneNo = 01917_999_720L;

> Using single catch statement for throwing multiple exception by using “|” operator

```
catch(IOException | NullPointerException ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();   
    }
```

> No need to close() resources because Java 7 provides try-with-resources statement

```
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("movies.txt");
      DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos)) {
              dos.writeUTF("Java 7 Block Buster");
  } catch(IOException e) {
        // log the exception
  }
```

> binary literals with prefix “0b” or “0B”

Answer (score 0):

I think  **ForkJoinPool** and related enhancement to Executor Framework is an important addition in Java 7.

Answer (score -2):

The following list contains links to the the enhancements pages in the Java SE 7.

```
Swing
IO and New IO
Networking
Security
Concurrency Utilities
Rich Internet Applications (RIA)/Deployment
    Requesting and Customizing Applet Decoration in Dragg able Applets
    Embedding JNLP File in Applet Tag
    Deploying without Codebase
    Handling Applet Initialization Status with Event Handlers
Java 2D
Java XML – JAXP, JAXB, and JAX-WS
Internationalization
java.lang Package
    Multithreaded Custom Class Loaders in Java SE 7
Java Programming Language
    Binary Literals
    Strings in switch Statements
    The try-with-resources Statement
    Catching Multiple Exception Types and Rethrowing Exceptions with Improved Type Checking
    Underscores in Numeric Literals
    Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation
    Improved Compiler Warnings and Errors When Using Non-Reifiable Formal Parameters with Varargs Methods
Java Virtual Machine (JVM)
    Java Virtual Machine Support for Non-Java Languages
    Garbage-First Collector
    Java HotSpot Virtual Machine Performance Enhancements
JDBC
```

[Reference 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html) [Reference 2](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?tag=java-7)

Comment: You should give more short descriptions or examples instead of that list what we also able to find out in Java official page.