# Is there any way to catch multiple Java exceptions in a single catch clause (OLD JAVA VERSIONS)?

Tags: java, try-catch

I know it is a probable duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495926/can-i-catch-multiple-java-exceptions-in-the-same-catch-clause). But the answer to that question includes the `|` inside the `catch (..|..)` which is unsupported in the earlier Java versions. I am bound to use an old version though. I have the same response to any type of exception. So, I would like to combine my `catch` statements in one, like this:

```
try {...}
catch(Excetion1 e1 OR Exception2 e2 OR etc)
{
...
}
```

I tried to use the hash `|` instead of `OR`, with no result. Is there any work around for older Java versions?

Comment: catch(Exception1|Exception2 ex)

Comment: " Is there any work around for older Java versions?" No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have same response for all Exceptions then you can simply use

```
try {...}
catch(Exception ex)
{
...
}
```

Comment: this solution is right for me...it looks nice...i hope it works on the older versions.

Comment: catching Exception is not a good solution imo. if that is needed it is very often a symptom of a bad application design. I will advice you to create your own set of exceptions if it is a big project. For smaller projects handle the exceptions thrown separately, don't catch all in one catch.

Comment: @Vegard, thank you for advice (+1). i am dealing with a web application. the exceptions are different but...all i need is a shortcut for the time being...till i switch java versions

Answer (score 5):

Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html):

> In Java SE 7 and later, a single catch block can handle more than one type of exception

```
catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

If it doesn't work for you, make sure you're using the Java 7 JRE.

Comment: +1 I must say they found the ugliest syntax... :)

Answer (score 2):

in java 6: no

in java 7, yes:

```
catch( Exception1 | Exception2 e )
```