# how to play audio file in android from internal memory of phone

Tags: android

I want to make sample to play an audio file in android ,i want to play music from internal memory of phone .how to give path please suggest.

I am writing this,but facing java.io.IOException:prepare failed error

```
 final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
 try{ 
      mp.setDataSource(Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/1.mp3");
      mp.prepare();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Instead of getRootDirectory() use environment.getexternalstoragedirectory()

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this.

```
// Add permission to your menifest to Read File from your storage


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then in your JAVA class/Activity from where you are calling to load mp3 File.

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer;

        // Your Media Player will be called with Audio file here..
          private void loadAudio(){

            String fileName = "YourAudio.mp3";
            String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName;

            File file = new File(completePath); 

                 Uri myUri1 = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    try {
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri1);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        mPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    mPlayer.start();
            }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: What path your are getting in completepath String??.. Have you checked is it returning you the path?. Also your file is present directly in the storage or it is inside any folder?.

Comment: my music file is present in music  inside Media folder

Comment: Why you want READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for reading file from internal storage?

Comment: [Can I catch multiple Java exceptions in the same catch clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495926/can-i-catch-multiple-java-exceptions-in-the-same-catch-clause)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you didn't, add the following permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And then this code:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();    
try {
    mPlayer.setDataSource(path+"/audio/1.mp3"); 
    mPlayer.prepare();                              
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}     
mPlayer.start();
```

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` gets exactly the path to your external directory as it is, not the `Environment.getRootDirectory()`

Comment: Why you want READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for reading file from internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it work ,

```
   try {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    String   path ,Filename ,fomrmat ;
    path   = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/a/";
    Filename = "abc";
    fomrmat =".mp3";
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path + Filename + fomrmat);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
    Log.i("moh Service", "End try Player");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i("moh Service", e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please Set permissions