# How to check what constraint has been violated?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, exception

I'm used to check if the user try to store a valid data with cathcing the `ConsratinViolationException`, like that:

```
try {
    //persisitng to a db
} 
catch (ConstraintViolationException e){
    //Print message
}
```

I'm using `PostgreSQL` and now I'm under the isssue that the persisitng can violate more than one different constarints. How can I distiguish in the catch clause what exactly constraint has been violated?

I need to do that, because the message the programm will print depending on that.

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495926/can-i-catch-multiple-java-exceptions-in-the-same-catch-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like below

```
catch (ConstraintViolationException conEx) {
            if (conEx.getConstraintName().contains("xyz_fK")) {
                //TODO Project Entity is violating it's constrain
            } 
            LOGGER.Info( "My log message", conEx.getConstraintName());
            LOGGER.ERROR( "My log message", conEx);
```

Answer (score 2):

A `ConstraintViolationException` contains a `Set` of `ConstraintViolation`s. Each of it contains information about a single violation. You can retrieve this `Set` with `getConstraintViolations()` and then iterate over it to find out, what has gone wrong in detail.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html.