# How do I catch two exceptions at once as a separated case?

Tags: java, exception

I wonder how is it possible to catch two exceptions which I have already caught separately?

```
    private static boolean checkParameters(Scanner scnr) {
        boolean result = true;
        return result;
    }

private static MnthInYear createMonthInYear() throws IllegalArgumentException { 
        String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter month and year");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(a);
        MnthInYear obj = null;
        if (checkParameters(sc)) {
            try {
                obj = new MnthInYear(sc.next(), sc.nextInt());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException exc) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong month!");
            } catch (InputMismatchException exc2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong year!");
            } catch (NoSuchElementException exc3) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No data!");
            }
            sc.close();
        }
        return obj; 
    }
```

And I need to make something like this:

```
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException AND InputMismatchException) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong month and year!");
              }
```

How can I get this?

Comment: use `llegalArgumentException | InputMismatchException`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I catch multiple Java exceptions in the same catch clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495926/can-i-catch-multiple-java-exceptions-in-the-same-catch-clause)

Comment: Your error message, "wrong month AND year," seems to suggest that `new MnthInYear(...)` will throw both exceptions if both problems exist.  But that's not possible.  No single method activation can ever throw more than one Exception object.

Comment: You will only throw one exception to catch. If you want an exception for both month and year, you will need to roll a custom exception.

Comment: "it is already handled by the catch block for exception"

Answer (score 1):

Use this example

For this:

```
catch (IOException ex) {
   logger.log(ex);
   throw ex;
catch (SQLException ex) {
   logger.log(ex);
   throw ex;
}
```

Use this:

```
catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
   logger.log(ex);
   throw ex;
}
```

Visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Comment: Not what the original question was asking. He's asking if it's possible for a block of code to throw two exceptions concurrently and to catch them both simultaneously (as opposed to catching one or the other).

Comment: Upvoting cause I think the downvote is unfair, question is a bit obscure.  Yes question seems to want to catch two exceptions at the same time, but it's not obvious (and not supported or really coherent), so upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, no, you can't do that. Once one exception is thrown, control moves to the relevant `catch` block and the next one won't be thrown. What you probably want instead is to implement a validation pattern where you validate the input, aggregate any errors with the input, and then summarize it at the end of validation with a single message.

Comment: Have a look at this article, it's nicely explained there: http://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, if anyone is interested in.

```js
private static boolean checkParameters(Scanner scnr) {
        boolean result = true;
        String msgError = "Invalid";
        
        try {
            month = scnr.next();
            mnth = MnthInYear.Month.valueOf(month);//class MnthInYear defines enum Month
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exc) {
            msgError += "month!";
            result = false;
        }
        try {
            year = scnr.nextInt();
            if (year < 0) {
                msgError += "year!";
                result = false;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            msgError += "month and year!";
            result = false;
        }
        if (msgError != "") {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,msgError);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Thanks for your answers!