# Retrofit2 synchronous call handling

Tags: java, java-8, retrofit2

In my project, we need to call rest API using retrofit client from several places and at each place we call retrofit client's execute method, we have to handle checked IOException, resulting a lot of try catch blocks. Is there any way I can handle this

Answer (score 0):

As you surely know in Java you have *checked* and *unchecked* exceptions:

- unchecked: descend from `RuntimeException`. You're fine with them
- checked: everything else. You'll have to **catch** them or the compilation will fail

The `execute()` method is defined to throw several checked exceptions so you will have to catch them. Alternatives?

- Change it to an asynchronous call and provide a method that will handle the exceptions
- Wrap the call in another method/class that already handles the exceptions
- Try [multiple catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495926/can-i-catch-multiple-java-exceptions-in-the-same-catch-clause)