# Is there a way to compare multiple (non-boolean) things at once using | or & in Java, similar to how you can catch multiple exceptions using |?

Tags: java, boolean, equality

Normally, I would have to type something like

```
if(a == x || b == x) {...}
```

But I saw that when using try/catch blocks, you can do stuff like this:

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {}
```

Is there something similar I can do with equality statements, like

```
if((a | b) == x) {...}
```

?

Comment: Unfortunately not. What you saw is just the syntactic sugar added in 1.7 for `multi-catch`. Boolean expressions can't be chained like that.

Comment: As per [this high voted comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495968/314291), it was perhaps unfortunate for Java 7 to choose bitwise or when catching multiple exceptions. It was always going to create confusion.

Answer (score 5):

No. The least you can do is `||`. Other than multi catch block, operator `|` gets treated as [bitwise OR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) and that is not what you needed. Inshort NO.