# Why does splitting a composite catch statement get rid of a verifyError?

Tags: java

### Problem

I had the following catch statement which was a problem:

```
} catch (DataException | JSONException exception) {
    throw new RuntimeException(exception);
}
```

I was seeing the following exception / error in the logs:

WARN annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver: Resolved [org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 93
Exception Details:
Location:

```
    my/code/aspose/AsposeDataSourceBuilder.getDataSource(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/aspose/words/net/System/Data/DataSet; @93: astore_1
  Reason:
    Type 'org/json/JSONException' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/RuntimeException' (stack map, stack[0])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @0
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/lang/Object' }
    stack: { 'org/json/JSONException' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @93
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/lang/Object' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/RuntimeException' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: bb00 0259 b700 03b6 0004 b600 054c 2b2a
    0x0000010: b600 064d bb00 0759 2cb7 0008 4ebb 0009
    0x0000020: 59b7 000a 120b b600 0c2d b800 0db6 000c
    0x0000030: 120e b600 0cb6 000f 3a04 bb00 1059 1211
    0x0000040: b700 123a 0519 05bb 0013 5919 04b2 0014
    0x0000050: b600 15b7 0016 b600 1757 1905 b04c bb00
    0x0000060: 1a59 2bb7 001b bf
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [0, 92] => handler: 93
    bci [0, 92] => handler: 93
  Stackmap Table:
    same_locals_1_stack_item_extended(@93,Object[#67])
```

I ran across the following Github issue/commits where they split a single catch into multiple ones - and this seemed to fix the error.

https://github.com/Wikidata/Wikidata-Toolkit/commit/0d214bb8870c29c0b688db4fda71ce8a64b4a46e
https://github.com/Wikidata/Wikidata-Toolkit/issues/58
[image]

So I split the catch statement and now it also works for me:

```
} catch (DataException e1) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e1);
        }catch(JSONException e2){
            throw new RuntimeException(e2);
        }
```

Update

In case it helps, here are the two inheritence trees from the two exception types:

[image]

### Question

Why does splitting the catch statement solve the error?

There's a similar question by MatKuhr [here](https://github.com/Wikidata/Wikidata-Toolkit/issues/58#issuecomment-627280175) ... but I don't understand the problem/solution yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804355/java-lang-verifyerror-stack-map-does-not-match-the-one-at-exception-handler)