# Occasional java.lang.VerifyError on application startup or workflow execution

Tags: java, jackson, aspectj, verifyerror

In an application that has been stable for several months, we recently started seeing several cases where a `java.lang.VerifyError`is being thrown, sometimes at application startup and sometimes during a workflow execution (after the same application launches successfully).

Here is an example of what we see:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/example/XYZController.doSomething()Lorg/springframework/http/ResponseEntity; @383: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Throwable' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Exception'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @383
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/example/XYZController', 'java/util/List', 'java/lang/Throwable', top, top, 'org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint' }
    stack: { 'org/slf4j/Logger', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/Throwable' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ....
    0000010: .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ....
    0000020: .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ....
    0000030: .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ....     
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [357, 371] => handler: 374
    bci [357, 371] => handler: 374
    bci [357, 371] => handler: 374
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@56,{Object[#231],Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Object[#624]},{Object[#555],Object[#624],Object[#558],Object[#626]})
    full_frame(@65,{Object[#231],Integer,Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Object[#624]},{})
    same_frame(@98)
    full_frame(@167,{Object[#231],Object[#232],Object[#233],Object[#306],Integer,Object[#311],Top,Object[#624]},{})
    same_frame(@206)
    full_frame(@209,{Object[#231],Object[#232],Object[#233],Object[#306],Top,Top,Top,Object[#624]},{})
    full_frame(@219,{Object[#231],Object[#232],Object[#233],Object[#306],Integer,Top,Top,Object[#624]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@313)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@374,Object[#622])
    full_frame(@393,{Object[#231],Object[#232],Object[#233],Object[#306],Top,Top,Top,Object[#624]},{})
```

The above is just one occurrence but we see this happen on multiple classes at different times.

By analyzing the bytecode using `javap`, we see that the verify error is always thrown when attempting to load a `catch` block that has a combination of checked and unchecked exceptions.

Like:

```
try {
    ...
    ...
} catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    doSomething(ex.getMessage()); // ex.getMessage() is where the VerifyError points to (shown below)
}
```

The corresponding `javap` output is:

```
383: invokevirtual #32  // Method java/lang/Exception.getMessage:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

The reference to `e.getMessage()` and the fact that the catch block is a combination of checked and unchecked exceptions is the only thing common across all the occurrences of the verify error.

I understand that the `VerifyError` is usually seen when libraries built using different versions of the JDK interact but we have more or less ruled that out, partly because of the intermittent nature of the error.

Also, we use aspectjweaver for load-time weaving, and the fact that it is intermittent led us down the path that there's possibly an issue with aspectjweaver (as noted here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=550705). We use v1.9.2 as well and so we're now evaluating the behavior after upgrading the aspectjweaver to 1.9.6, as suggested in the eclipse thread.

While we're still evaluating this change, we also broke down the exception handler to separate catch blocks for each exception as well.

So far, after the changes above and with the limited number of restarts of the application, we have not seen it crash with the verify error, but there's no way for us to be confident that we have indeed fixed the root cause. So, we'll probably have to let it play out for a while.

In the meantime, I'd like to check if anyone here has seen similar behaviors that they were able to fix with confidence and also try to get the details of the fix.

**EDIT** (based on questions posed by kriegaex):

---

Java version being used

```
Runtime Java version: openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
Compile time Java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
```

We'll soon be moving to JDK 11 for both compile and run time. This is a product with a lot of legacy code and the pace of upgrades, especially to the JDK versions will be very slow.

The reason for attempting an upgrade from one outdated aspectj version (1.9.2) to another outdated version (1.9.6) is solely based on the eclipse thread that had a very similar problem that we have (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=550705). If we know for a fact that this is *not* the root cause, we'd likely not do the upgrade at all as doing so involves running regression tests on 40 different components owned by teams across the world (mostly automated but there still are quite a few manual tests). Having said that, if we know for a fact that the aspectj versions are completely backward compatible, that may enable us to move to even the latest possible version.

One more data point that I missed providing earlier was that one major change that went into effect in our product recently was the upgrade of Jackson from v2.7.9 to v2.12.7 - there were a lot of (documented) backward incompatibilities here and a lot of legacy code had to be modified to perform this upgrade. There's a theory that this upgrade is exposing problems in the product that were long hidden - but it's just a theory.

I am unable to provide a reproducer because we're not able to reproduce this locally. It's always a coin toss as to whether the error happens or not. Sometimes, it happens at application startup, sometimes after the application starts up successfully, and sometimes never - all with the same codebase.

**One more edit**

---

Stackoverflow was wise enough to show this as a related problem: [java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804355/java-lang-verifyerror-stack-map-does-not-match-the-one-at-exception-handler?rq=2)

This is kind of as close to our problem that I can expect but we've all but ruled out conflicting jackson libraries. But we'll dig in further

Comment: Please provide a reproducer on GitHub, ideally a Maven project. Nobody can debug nonexistent code. Please also explain why you are upgrading from one outdated AspectJ version to another outdated one. Other details like Java version used and compiler settings would also be helpful.

Comment: @kriegaex - I've edited my question to provide the details you were looking for - probably not what you wanted but unfortunately, that's what i have so far.

Comment: It indeed looks like jweaver rather than a virus/corrupt code. The .class files could be somehow validated separately: probably okay considering the LTS and version number. Personally I would first look into SonarLint, `@SuppressWarning* and unsafe, reflective or synthetic code or remote classes, RMI.

Comment: Other than recommending to use the latest AspectJ version 1.9.20.1, I cannot do anything more, if you do not provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I do not even know if you really use AspectJ or simply Spring AOP, because there is zero code.  The latest version certainly includes more bugfixes than1.9.6. Of course, this incurs the risk that there are also new bugs, but that risk is the same as when upgrading to 1.9.6, is it not? There shouldnot be any incompatibilities, but if there are, you will notice during application startup or shortly thereafter.

Comment: The best way to create an MCVE is to strip off as much as you can from your big application as possible, step by step, and verifying that the smallest version still exhibits the problematic behaviour. If the error is flaky, write a test or a shell script that runs the app or the problematic part repeatedly, until the error occurs. Then, if necessary, anonymise the minimal reproducer and put it on GitHub with instructions how to reproduce the error. If you are unable to do that, this is the end our conversation here. Spoiler: I am the current AspectJ maintainer.

Comment: @JoopEggen: What is jweaver supposed to be?

Comment: @kriegaex Typo, aspectjweaver from aspectj's AOP.

Comment: @kriegaex - I completely understand that you're not able to help without any code references to reproduce it. I am well aware of the need to build an MVCE and have been trying to do just that for the past few days - a barebones application with just the required dependencies like spring, aspectjweaver and jackson. I just don't want to push some code as problematic without personally having the ability to reproduce it consistently, only for others to reply that it works for them just fine. I'll update this thread when I am able to produce an MVCE. (1/2)

Comment: Until then, I am just looking for some general pointers from the community if they've seen this behavior before, how they approached it, and how they solved it. I am in no way pinpointing a problem with aspectjweaver (except for what I found on the Eclipse thread) nor am I asking you to debug this problem without the information that you need. But thank you for your interest in helping and as mentioned earlier, I'll keep this thread posted when I do have an MVCE (2/2)