# How to handle all the java.net exceptions in a single catch block?

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to handle the exceptions that are a part of the java.net package. I went through the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html) and I saw 12 exceptions belonging to that package, but I couldn't find the parent class of these exceptions.

So far what I have tried is:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    if(e instanceof org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException)
        sendException("Problem is with the selenium web driver");
    else if(e instanceof java.net.Exception) //I need help with this line
        sendException("There is some problem with the network");
}
```

After trying this, I get the following error message

> unable to resolve class java.net.Exception

How can I catch the java.net exceptions?

Comment: If you are going to process this exceptions differently then catch it in differents blocks, else you can use `catch (Exception1 | Exception2 | Exception3 e) { }`.

Comment: else if(e.getClass().getPackage().startsWith("java.net"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.net.Exception doesn't exist, java.lang.Exception does.

To check that the package is java.net, use e.getClass().getPackage():

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    if(e instanceof org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException)
        sendException("Problem is with the selenium web driver");
    else if(e.getClass().getPackage().startsWith("java.net"))
        sendException("There is some problem with the network");
}
```

Comment: This solution seems great. but the only problem is `e.getClass().getPackage()` gives the output "package java.net, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.8" (in my machine). So `startsWith` will fail. Please replace the `startsWith` with `contains` :)

Answer (score 4):

First off, the reason that you can't catch `java.net.Exception` is that it doesn't exist!  The actual `Exception` class `java.lang.Exception` but that is NOT the exception you should be catching.

So what should you catch?

Unfortunately, there there is no single supertype for all networking exceptions (and not non-networking exceptions).  Most networking exceptions have `java.io.IOException` as an ancestor, but many `IOException` subclasses are declared in `java.io` and other places and have nothing to do with networking.

(One `java.net.*` exception that doesn't descend from `IOException`; i.e. `java.net.URISyntaxException`.  But that is an unchecked exception, and it is not indicative of a "network problem".)

So one approach would be to catch `IOException`.  You could further refine this by using reflection to get the package name of the exception class (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57002571/139985); e.g.

```
} catch (org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException e) {
    sendException("Problem is with the selenium web driver");
} catch (IOException e) {
    if (e.getClass().getPackage().startsWith("java.net"))
        sendException("There is some problem with the network");
    else {
        throw e;  // Or diagnose differently
    }
}
```

But there is another wrinkle: even `java.net.*` exceptions don't necessarily indicate a "network problem".  For example, if you get an `UnknownHostException`, that's probably not a problem with the network.  It is more likely that you (or the user) have supplied the wrong hostname.  Likewise, some flavors of `ConnectException` indicate that the network is fine, but the required remote service is not running on that host.  It might be down, or you might have gotten the wrong host.

Finally, if you translate all `java.net` exceptions to a simple catch-all "network problem" message, you will be discarding information that could be used to diagnose the actual problem.  So, I'd advise you not to *try* to do what you are proposing.  Not even in a "friendly" user interface.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you for mentioning IOException even though it doesn't technically cover every single possible network exception.

Answer (score 3):

You can catch java.net Exceptions like this :

```
try {

}
catch (
    BindException 
    | ConnectException 
    | HttpRetryException
    | MalformedURLException
    | NoRouteToHostException
    | PortUnreachableException
    | ProtocolException
    | SocketException
    | SocketTimeoutException
    | UnknownHostException
    | UnknownServiceException
    | URISyntaxException
    e
){
    // do stuff with e
}
```

But what is the point if you are going to call `instanceof` after to process each exception differently?

In this case you should use different catch blocks.

Comment: I am not going to process each of the java.net exceptions differently. I am considering all the exceptions that belong to the same package as one. I know your solution could work, but I was looking for a more optimised and simple solution.

Comment: All right, so unless someone shows me another solution, the comment of **super** up above is the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`java.net.Exception` doesn't exist and you cannot catch exceptions of classes from a specific package in this way.
Considering that network exceptions always start by `java.net` is wrong too.
Some network exception don't start by `java.net` and exceptions can also be wrapped by another exception. For example `java.net.SocketException` could be wrapped by `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.
You will not handle it because that is not a `java.net` exception.

Handling the exception with `instanceOf` looks not helpful either.
Specifying a specific exception in the `catch` clause is enough.
Note also that an exception is self-explanatory and should contain in its state all relevant information : you don't need to map the exception to a textual message as you do.

What you want to send/log is exploiting the exception class/message/cause/stracktrace associated to. What you do is just interpretation of the exception meaning that would be error prone.

so do that :

```
catch(Exception e){
    sendException(e); 
}

public void sendException(Exception e){
   // exploit e.getClass(), e.getMessage() or e.getStackTrace()
   ...
}
```

Note that in some cases you want to catch some specific exceptions because you have a specific processing for them :

```
catch(WebDriverException e){
     processWebDriverException(e);
}
catch(Exception e){
     processAnyOtherException(e);
}
```

Comment: Hey @davidxxx I don't have enough reputations to do a downvote.Btw I have already handled some of the exceptions like malformedurlexception and sockettimeout exception. But for the remaining 10 exceptions, I need to send a message like `"network error occured while trying to access"+url`. This message should not be sent if any IO exception occurs, This should be sent only if an exception belonging to java.net package occurs. So handling all the exceptions by `catch(Exception e)` won't work. I had to write 10 catch blocks for the java.net exceptions but that would be a waste of time.

Comment: I understand your requirement. But I think that stating at a single place and explicitly exceptions classes that you want to catch is better because you want to apply a specific processing for them. You could use a Set to make it more readable. `Set<Class<?>> exceptionClasses = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ConnectException.class, UnknownHostException.class, ...)); try(..){catch (Exception e) { if (exceptionClasses.contains(e.getClass()){ {send(...)};}`

Answer (score 0):

If there is no common superclass, there is no way to catch these exceptions in a single clause. You might want to check out this post, but I would agree with you that it's not pretty if you have to specify 12 exceptions:

[Can I catch multiple Java exceptions in the same catch clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495926/can-i-catch-multiple-java-exceptions-in-the-same-catch-clause)

Answer (score -2):

```
Example

Try{

Code where your exception occuring

}

Catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to print the stacktrace. I want to send a particular message based on the type of exception.