# This method throws two different exceptions. How could man catch the two exceptions and prints exception catched for both exception types to console?

Tags: java, exception, catch-exception

```
public class CatchingExceptions {
    private int erroneousMethod(int p) {
        if (p == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int x = 0x01;
        return p / (x >> Math.abs(p)); // this line will throw!
    }
```

The task is to implement the following method to catch and print the two exceptions.

```
public void catchExceptions(int passthrough) {

        erroneousMethod(passthrough); // will throw!
        try{
          ????
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            System.out.println("???? ");
        }
}
```

Comment: Call the method inside the `try` block instead of before it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I catch multiple Java exceptions in the same catch clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495926/can-i-catch-multiple-java-exceptions-in-the-same-catch-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Call the method inside the `try` block:

```
public void catchExceptions(int passthrough) {
    try{
        erroneousMethod(passthrough);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) { // catches all unchecked exceptions
        String message = e.getMessage() == null ? "" : (": " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + message);
    }
}
```