# Does qualifying a method call degrade performance in Java?

Tags: java, android, performance, methods, bytecode

I'm guessing the following two functions compile to the exact same byte-code, but I beg to ask the question.  Does qualifying a method call where it is not necessary degrade performance?

For example:

```
package com.my;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main); // Fully qualified 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      // Not fully qualified
    }

}
```

The standard is to use the latter, but does the fully qualified call `this.setContentView()` have any negative effects?

Comment: Being more specific should never *degrade* performance, though it may not *help* it.

Comment: If I were to ask the question again, I would inverse the proposition.. you are right, the degradation would result from *not* qualifying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there isn't any sort of penalty. Both calls will use `invokespecial` in the bytecode to invoke the member method.

In standard Java, the following code:

```
public class TestQualified {

   private void someMethod() {
   }

   public void otherMethod() {
       this.someMethod();
       someMethod();
   }
}
```

yields the following bytecode:

```
Compiled from "TestQualified.java"
public class TestQualified extends java.lang.Object{
public TestQualified();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

private void someMethod();
  Code:
   0:   return

public void otherMethod();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #2; //Method someMethod:()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   invokespecial   #2; //Method someMethod:()V
   8:   return

}
```

As you can see, both calls are the same.

Now Android converts the `.class` files into dalvik bytecode using the `dx` tool, which outputs `.dex` files. Since the `.class` files don't show any distinction between the two invocations, the corresponding `.dex` file will show no difference either:

```
Processing 'TestQualified.dex'...
Opened 'TestQualified.dex', DEX version '035'
Class #0            -
  Class descriptor  : 'LTestQualified;'
  Access flags      : 0x0001 (PUBLIC)
  Superclass        : 'Ljava/lang/Object;'
  Interfaces        -
  Static fields     -
  Instance fields   -
  Direct methods    -
    #0              : (in LTestQualified;)
      name          : '<init>'
      type          : '()V'
      access        : 0x10001 (PUBLIC CONSTRUCTOR)
      code          -
      registers     : 1
      ins           : 1
      outs          : 1
      insns size    : 4 16-bit code units
0000e4:                                        |[0000e4] TestQualified.<init>:()V
0000f4: 7010 0300 0000                         |0000: invoke-direct {v0}, Ljava/lang/Object;.<init>:()V // method@0003
0000fa: 0e00                                   |0003: return-void
      catches       : (none)
      positions     : 
        0x0000 line=1
      locals        : 
        0x0000 - 0x0004 reg=0 this LTestQualified; 

    #1              : (in LTestQualified;)
      name          : 'someMethod'
      type          : '()V'
      access        : 0x0002 (PRIVATE)
      code          -
      registers     : 1
      ins           : 1
      outs          : 0
      insns size    : 1 16-bit code units
0000fc:                                        |[0000fc] TestQualified.someMethod:()V
00010c: 0e00                                   |0000: return-void
      catches       : (none)
      positions     : 
        0x0000 line=4
      locals        : 
        0x0000 - 0x0001 reg=0 this LTestQualified; 

  Virtual methods   -
    #0              : (in LTestQualified;)
      name          : 'otherMethod'
      type          : '()V'
      access        : 0x0001 (PUBLIC)
      code          -
      registers     : 1
      ins           : 1
      outs          : 1
      insns size    : 7 16-bit code units
000110:                                        |[000110] TestQualified.otherMethod:()V
000120: 7010 0200 0000                         |0000: invoke-direct {v0}, LTestQualified;.someMethod:()V // method@0002
000126: 7010 0200 0000                         |0003: invoke-direct {v0}, LTestQualified;.someMethod:()V // method@0002
00012c: 0e00                                   |0006: return-void
      catches       : (none)
      positions     : 
        0x0000 line=7
        0x0003 line=8
        0x0006 line=9
      locals        : 
        0x0000 - 0x0007 reg=0 this LTestQualified; 

  source_file_idx   : 3 (TestQualified.java)
```

You can see that both calls are made using `invoke-direct`. Hence there is no performance penalty here either.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. It's all the same for the compiler. Using `this` reference may be seen as a reading help, like the underscores in the [java7 number literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212558/java-7-underscore-in-numeric-literals)