# New features in JDK 1.6 and 1.7

Tags: java, java-6, java-7

I know JDK 1.5 pretty well. As we all know, besides new API (such as AtomicInteger, for example), there were major language changes such as providing support for generic, adding enum, prividing auto-boxing and auto-unboxing and so on.

I want to find some resources that have preferably short description of new features in JDK 1.6 and 1.7 (for *big* new features I prefer to read complete explanations). As far changes of API only major changes is acceptable and short review of new one (if I recall write there is new way to read characters from the console, for example). As far as features goes I want to find *complete list* (such changes in the allocation of the objects, now JVM can actually creates objects on the stack for optimization purposes, for example, but I don't know the details).

For JDK 1.6
[Core Java Technology Features](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/JavaSE6_build39.html) and [Java™ SE 6 compatibility with J2SE 5.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html). For JDK 1.7 [Working with Java SE 7 Exception Changes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html), but it is incomplete list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JDK 1.6
Compatibility http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html

Core Java Technology Features http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javase6-build39-139826.html
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/JavaSE6_build39.html

Java SE 6 Performance White Paper http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/6-performance-137236.html

Quick note, implementation of the java.util.ArrayList was changed (due to bug [6260652](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6260652)).

---

JDK 1.7

Java SE 7 and JDK 7 Compatibility http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html (there  are some behavioral incompatibilities).

Java SE 7 Features and Enhancements http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html

**A look at Java 7's new features** http://radar.oreilly.com/2011/09/java7-features.html (see also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html for diamond operator)

(Misc) JDK 7: New Interfaces, Classes, Enums, and Methods  http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/03/jdk-7-new-interfaces-classes-enums-and.html

Answer (score 10):

1.6 changes: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/features-141434.html

1.7 changes: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/ (Language enhancements: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/coin/)

Comment: This is list is incomplete as I mentioned before. It can be a good point to start, but it isn't the answer that I am looking for.

Comment: @alexsmail - actually, your question links to **different** lists than the ones in the Answer.

Comment: @Stephen C, Oh, I see now. It was unintentional. I just make some research prior to ask the question. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Java Programming Language Enhancements

**[Enhancements in Java SE 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html)**

1. [Binary Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10961101/1697099)
2. [Strings in switch Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10240598/1697099)
3. [Try with Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739460/1697099)
4. [Multiple Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495968/1697099)
5. [underscore in literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6212642/1697099)
6. [Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation using Diamond Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14909875/1697099)
7. [Improved Compiler Warnings and Errors When Using Non-Reifiable Formal Parameters with Varargs Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/non-reifiable-varargs.html)

**Enhancements in Java SE 6**
No language changes were introduced in Java SE 6.