# Is Tomcat 7 now compatible with Java 7?

Tags: tomcat7, java-7

If not, when is it foreseen for?

If yes, do you know if there is something special to migrate an existing installation of Tomcat 7/Java 6 to Tomcat 7/Java 7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Officially](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) Java 1.6 or later is supported.

[image]

[This post](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/08/25/apache-tomcat-8-and-java-7-will-they-work-together) goes into more detail.

Comment: The "later" is not true anymore, documentation has changed. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9294694/1140748

Comment: I've updated the first link.  It was mistakenly pointing to the "Building Tomcat" page which is not for users but for people making changes to Tomcat itself.  The page for Tomcat users says Java 6 or later.

Comment: Thank you for the update ;) The migration guide also confirm that. I've corrected my answer too.

Answer (score 3):

**EDITED**

As pointed out by [***sourcedelica***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294761/1140748) the [Official documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) says you can use JDK 1.6 or later so you can use Tomcat 7 with JDK 1.7.

Also check the [**Tomcat 7 Migration Guide**](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html) .

---

By the way your applications developed with JDK 1.6 **may fail** using JDK 1.7, especially if you use classes in `sun.*` packages ([which is bad](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)). Even if retro-compatibility is strong, some corner cases exist, see [**Oracle list of incompatibilities**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities) for more details.

You can also find some stuff about this in this SO article : [New features in JDK 1.6 and 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784158/new-features-in-jdk-1-6-and-1-7)

Comment: looks like they updated the documentation page - it no longer says "or later"

Comment: That's true. I don't see any JDK 1.6 or later as of Feb 27, 2014 from Tomcat 7 document.

Answer (score 3):

Last month (Feb. 2013) I updated my Java from 1.6 to 1.7. However, the update has repercussion - Tomcat 7.0.37 is not running anymore after the Java update.

I tried un-installing the Java 1.7, replace with 1.6 and the Apache Tomcat runs smoothly again. I forgot to capture the exact error message and I couldn't find also on the server logs.

FYI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i am using `jdk6` with `tomcat 7`.i have following issues.

```
INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6.
```

To suppress this message, run `Tomcat` on `Java 7`, remove the `WebSocket JAR`s from `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` or add the `WebSocketJARs` to the `tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip` property in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties`.

Note that the deprecated `Tomcat 7 WebSocket API` will be available.