# Tomcat 7 with Java 7 JRE_HOME not handling Java 7 beans

Tags: tomcat7, java-7

I've set-up my *Tomcat 7* on *Ubuntu 12* with a *Java 7* JRE_HOME:

```
$ /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/version.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Server built:   Apr 11 2012 12:24:08
Server number:  7.0.26.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Architecture:   i386
JVM Version:    1.7.0_03-b147
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

But when deploying a simple JSF application compiled to 1.7 Tomcat complains with

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/corejsf/UserBean : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.corejsf.UserBean)
```

When I change my Ant build.xml to compile to "1.6" the application deploys fine. Is this incompatibility with Java 7 to be expected? There is a 6-months-old [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294355/is-tomcat-7-now-compatible-with-java-7) on Tomcat 7 / Java 7 compatibility but the answers there seem to suggest that Java 7 is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same issue.
Here are my steps:

Edit file:

> /etc/default/tomcat7

Replace JAVA_HOME

From

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-6-jdk

to

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_09

Restart Tomcat.

Comment: Wrong advice, simply install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel or openjdk-7-jdk: http://openjdk.java.net/install/ Then, edit /etc/default/tomcat7 so that it points to OpenJDK JDK 1.7 update 09 (currently 80).