# Does Tomcat 8 support Java 8?

Tags: tomcat

Is tomcat 8 (today as RC1 - see [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/changelog.html)) supporting Java 8, even if it is still in beta?

Among others Tomcat 8 supports Java EE 7:

- Websockets
- Servlet api 3.1 (Asynch servlet support)

I had trouble in the [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294355/is-tomcat-7-now-compatible-with-java-7) with Tomcat 7 / Java 7, that's why I am asking this question.

---

**Update**

An interesting article on infoq indicates that tomcat 8 is ready for java 8. Even Tomcat 7 would be.

See the article [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/04/spring-updated-for-java8?utm_campaign=infoq_content&utm_source=infoq&utm_medium=feed&utm_term=global)

---

If you see any compatibility issue, I will report it here.

Comment: Huh? Tomcat is just written in Java. Surely it will run on Java 7/8/9/10/11/etc like as every other Java program.

Comment: @BalusC he means if you can run applications written in Java 8.

Comment: @kirdie: that doesn't depend on Tomcat, but on JVM.

Comment: BalusC is wrong, of course. There are many subtle issues due to which Tomcat may fail to operate with a newer JRE.

Comment: BalusC is usually right about Tomcat. Care to elaborate on what issues Tomcat has with Java 8?

Comment: There were some issues running JSPs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243458/tomcat7-not-compiling-jsp-examples

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the [Tomcat Docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html):

> Any installed Java 7 or later JRE (32-bit or 64-bit) may be used.

Comment: The version matrix also says the same: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Answer (score 10):

Tested Tomcat 7.0.50 with Web app written on Java 8 + Spring 4.0.2, using lambda expressions, method references and streams - works like a charm!

Comment: Maybe... or not. Tomcat officially supports Java 7, not Java 8.

Comment: I wrote about my real expirience. Officialy - yes, the site of Tomcat tell that Java 7 and later versions supported.

Comment: Depends on the tomcat7 version. The version on ubuntu repositories seems to have some problems. But 7.0.50 should be ok.

Comment: But if you are using Mojarra 2.1 (2.1.29 I have tested) and even with Tomcat 7.0.68 (TomEE 1.7.4 tested) you can not use lambda expressions. Otherwise the following exception will be raised:

INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.29 ( 20140702-1445 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.1.29@13392) for context '/reflex'
márc. 23, 2016 7:10:35 DU org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener configureFactory
ERROR j.e.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config - Unknow type constant pool 18 at position 41
ERROR j.e.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config - Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 42

Answer (score 5):

It does not support out of the box.  You must make some changes.
in apache home\conf\web.xml add the following lines in the jsp section.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>compiler</param-name>
    <param-value>modern</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
    <param-value>1.8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
    <param-value>1.8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>suppressSmap</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I also added to my classpath in setenv.sh (or bat) the follwing entry:
export `CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$CLASSPATH`

Note that I also need to have java_home set to 1.8 (little bit of a duh here, but may be worth mentioning)

Here are some sources:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jasper-howto.html
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-dev/201301.mbox/%3C7CF0788AAB53854AB15567D68F41960238297F32@CH1PRD0410MB369.namprd04.prod.outlook.com%3E

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat 8.0 is designed to run on Java 7. For reference, the following specifications have been supported:

1. Tomcat 6: Servlet 2.5, JSP 2.1, and EL 2.1.
2. Tomcat 7: Servlet 3.0, JSP 2.2, and EL 2.2.
3. Tomcat 8: Servlet 3.1, JSP 2.3, and EL 3.0. In addition, there is support for a new specification, Java WebSocket 1.0.

See more at: http://blog.gopivotal.com/products/apache-tomcat-8-what-it-is-what-you-need-to-know#sthash.nVw8CTJ9.dpuf

Comment: Nope. Tomcat 8 runs on Java 7 *or later*.

Comment: also websockets are available from tomcat 7

Answer (score 2):

I have tried on Linux and it does not work. When it comes to executing a lambda expression in JSP page the following error is thrown

Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
Apache Tomcat/8.0.14

it runs on JDK jdk1.8.0_25

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Chewy, I was searching for last 1 hour to compile lambdas within jsp it worked for me.

Updated the jsp section in tomcat's web.xml as follows (only this much change was required):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compiler</param-name>
        <param-value>modern</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>suppressSmap</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>fork</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize compile value inside web..xml
then you can able to Used Tomcat8.

Tomcat 8: Servlet 3.1, JSP 2.3, and EL 3.0.