# Java 8 error: HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, tomcat7, java-8

I have installed java 8 and removed previously installed java 7 and its folders, and also re-installed Apache Tomcat 7 with security options, I did all the environment variables settings and my tomcat 7 started with no problem, but when I tried to open the localhost `http://localhost:8080` then i am getting the following error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

The error have a some description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

It seems i did nothing wrong, but are there an issues with Java 8 and Apache Tomcat 7.

Comment: It would be better if you post the jsp file which is causing the problem.

Comment: <%@page import="java.util.Map.Entry"%>
is there is your jsp..????

Comment: i was just checking the tomcat home page after installation, and http://localhost:8080 thats how its done. i haven't created any jsp  file.

Comment: Did you try with latest version ?

Comment: Latest version of tomcat..? No!

Comment: I have the same problem. Works with 1.7, as soon as I use 1.8 it doesn't work.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243458/tomcat7-not-compiling-jsp-examples, solution: use Tomcat 7 build compatible with Java 8