# Tomcat 7 with Java 8 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, tomcat7, raspbian

**UPDATE** tomcat8 seems to work in this scenario as I could open the /manager/ page as required. While this does not solve the original problem state here I advise you to use tomcat8 from debian backports in this scenario!

Raspbian delivers the current Java 8 in version

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apt# java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

after installing tomcat 7 i reverted to the tomcat7 version provided by debian backports which is

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apt# dpkg -l |grep tomcat
ii  libtomcat7-java                       7.0.56-1~bpo70+2                        all          Servlet and JSP engine -- core libraries
ii  tomcat7                               7.0.56-1~bpo70+2                        all          Servlet and JSP engine
ii  tomcat7-admin                         7.0.56-1~bpo70+2                        all          Servlet and JSP engine -- admin web applications
ii  tomcat7-common                        7.0.56-1~bpo70+2                        all          Servlet and JSP engine -- common files
```

which according to [tomcat7 not compiling jsp examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243458/tomcat7-not-compiling-jsp-examples) should work. This, however, is not the case as the manager page leaves me with the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [1] in the generated java file: [/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/manager/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
```

Does anybody know what the actual problem here could be?

Comment: Are you running the Java SDK or Java JRE?

Comment: oracle-java8-jdk as installed by default in raspbian. As just updated, tomcat8 runs.

Comment: @col.panic How did you get tomcat8 on the raspberry on raspbian? Did you have to compile it yourself?

Comment: @flindeberg I added an answer explaining how I got it working, though not the 'best' solution, IMHO. Please, col.panic, add an answer explaining how you did it.

Answer (score 24):

As stated in the question, Tomcat as provided by Raspbian doesn't work with Java 8. I managed to install Tomcat 8 following the instructions on [this blog](https://tommorrisblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/installing-apache-tomcat-8-on-a-raspberry-pi/). To avoid linkrot and correct a small mistake, I'll quote the text there almost literally (updated for version 8.0.24):

> ## Installing Apache Tomcat 8 on a Raspberry Pi
>
> On my Raspberry Pi I have already installed Apache 2 HTTP server and
>   hence this article does a basic install and configuration of Tomcat.
>   Firstly, update all installed packages:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Confirm that Java is already installed:
>
> ```
> pi@raspberrypi /usr/bin $ java -version
> java version "1.8.0"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
> ```
>
> Log in to the home directory for the pi user and download the desired
>   release of Tomcat:
>
> ```
> $ wget http://mirrors.axint.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.24/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.24.tar.gz
> ```
>
> Extract the zipped tarball:
>
> ```
> $ tar xvf apache-tomcat-8.0.24.tar.gz
> ```
>
> Add the following user XML element as the last child of the
>   tomcat-users parent element of
>   `~/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/conf/tomcat-users.xml` (this creates an admin
>   account called “system” who’s password is “raspberry”):
>
> ```
> <user username="system" password="raspberry" roles="manager-gui"/>
> ```
>
> Change the directory permissions on the following directorys, since by
>   default, the pi Linux user cannot write to them:
>
> *[NB: I didn't have to do this step, as in release 8.0.24, there was no directory `apache-tomcat-8.0.24/work/Catalina`]*
>
> Add a startup script called tomcat to the /etc/init.d directory, which
>   has the following contents:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> # /etc/init.d/tomcat
> # starts the Apache Tomcat service
> ### BEGIN INIT INFO
> # Provides:          tomcat
> # Required-Start:
> # Required-Stop:
> # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
> # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
> # X-Interactive:     true
> # Short-Description: Start/stop tomcat application server
> ### END INIT INFO
>
> export CATALINA_HOME="/home/pi/apache-tomcat-8.0.24"
> case "$1" in
> start)
>   if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh ];
>   then
>     echo $"Starting Tomcat"
>     /bin/su pi $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
>   fi
>   ;;
> stop)
>   if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh ];
>   then
>     echo $"Stopping Tomcat"
>     /bin/su pi $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
>   fi
>   ;;
> *)
>   echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
>   exit 1
>   ;;
> esac
> ```
>
> Use the update-rc.d command to add the appropriate links to the
>   /etc/rc?.d directories:
>
> ```
> $ sudo update-rc.d tomcat defaults
> ```
>
> Test that the tomcat server starts:
>
> ```
> $ sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat start
> ```
>
> On a web client, point your browser at `http://”Raspberry Pi IP Address”:8080`
>
> [image: Tomcat screenshot]
>
> Test that the tomcat server stops:
>
> ```
> $ sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat stop
> ```
>
> Finally, reboot the system and the Tomcat application server should
>   now start automatically on startup, and likewise when the system shuts
>   down.

All credits go to The Friday Night Project.

One thing to point out: to me, as a hardcore Linux user, this solution sounds a bit hacky, installing software in a user's home directory, but it works.

Comment: +1 works like a charm, only one small step missing, I had to give the new tomcat script the right permissions using $ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/tomcat.

Answer (score -1):

Steps to install Apache tomcat new version on raspberry pi:

1)sudo apt-get update

2)sudo apt-get install default-jdk

3)sudo wget http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.47/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.47.zip

4)sudo apt-get install unzip

5)sudo unzip apache-tomcat-8.5.47.zip

6)cd apache-tomcat-8.5.47/bin/

7)sudo chmod 700 *.sh

8)sudo ./startup.sh

In case you are getting a 404 error or if you want to install apache tomcat on port 80 then please visit the below link to know how to do that.

http://www.bytesofgigabytes.com/raspberrypi/install-apache-tomcat-on-raspberry-pi/