# Deployed EAR can't resolve class

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, classpath, ear

I have an EAR deployed on our development server (WebLogic 10.3.3) that runs fine.  Yet, when I take that same EAR and deploy it on a WebLogic 10.3.6 server running on my desktop, the deployment succeeds but I see an error when loading a JSP:

```
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /webclient/login/login.jsp
login.jsp:11:92: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I'm assuming that the EAR references some classes outside the EAR when running on the demo that I don't have on my desktop.

From what I can tell, on both machines the system classpath is simply the current dir.  The manifest.mf file in the EAR directory/meta-inf is empty and I didn't see manifest.mf files elsewhere that pointed outside the EAR.

What settings or files should I be looking at to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to check which version of jdk used to run WebLogic 10.3.6 (jdk7) i think it run with another version

Comment: Can you help me understand this better?  I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243458/tomcat7-not-compiling-jsp-examples and bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1080026 where the app server used an old compiler for a JSP which references a HashMap object that was built with JDK 8.  I do have JDK 8 on my desktop, but in my case, I have not rebuilt any classes.  Thanks.

Comment: The jsp pages will be compiled using the weblogic jdk so when you installed the weblogic (10.3.6) it asked you which jdk version you need the embedded version (jdk7 it contained in installation folder  ) or system version (jdk 8) if you selected the system version this issue will occur.
so you can check the jdk version for weblogic from setdomainenv.cmd from bin directory to know which version selected.

Comment: Check what your JAVA_HOME is set to before you launch startWebLogic via a command prompt. `echo %JAVA_HOME%`