# After update to JDK8, compilation error occurs in JSP: "The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, java-8

I recently updated my JDK version to 8. I have a piece of code which looks like :

```
     StringBuilder abc = new StringBuilder();
     abc.append("123");
```

when I run this, It is throwing error:

```
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I have updated all the dependencies of JDK, but noting helped.

Comment: Show us your imports.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved in package declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration)

Comment: How are you compiling? What is your project compiler compliance level set to?

Answer (score 3):

I just suffered it yesterday. It's because your server (tomcat I guess?) doesn't support Java 8 (for the version you've).

It's known that tomcat6 and some of the first version of tomcat7 **doesn't support Java 8**. You would have to update your server or compile it back with Java 7.

From the reference I leave below, [Brett Bryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140037/brett-ryan) said:

> I can confirm that apache-tomcat-7.0.35 does NOT have support for
>   JDK8, I can also confirm that apache-tomcat-7.0.50 DOES have support
>   for JDK8.

Reference: [Unable to compile class for JSP: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243458/tomcat7-not-compiling-jsp-examples/21322569#21322569)

Comment: same problem on my side, i had jdk8 in my eclipse set, and running my app on was liberty, after switch back to jkd7 everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

I have face the similar issue in java upgrade to v1.8. This problem is due to use of lower version of servlet api (< 3.0).

Solution: 1: Either degrade Java 8 to Java v7 
   or 
2: Upgrade the servlet api version to 3.0 or higher.

Comment: I just upgraded my Servlet version to 3.1 but didn't work. Is it required to upgrade the jetty too. My older jetty has version 6.5. Do I need to upgrade to Jetty 9?

Comment: Yes You have to bring Application server/container compatible with Latest Specification.