# Unable to get ExpectedOutput in SpringDaoMvc Application?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am getting this Exception-->

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

while trying to search a city with name X in Database.

Below is the StackTrace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MainServlet] in context with path [/SpringDaoMvc] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
at MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:43)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> Can anyone guide me how can i correct this?

BELOW IS MY CODE:

```
1)index.html


<form action="MainServlet" method="get">
<input type="text" name="city">
<input type="submit" name="getDetails">
</form>
```

2)MainServlet:

```
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
 ModelBean bobj;
 public MainServlet() 
 {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
 public void init()
 {
     //Activate SpringContainer
    ApplicationContext bfact=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ModelCfg.xml");

     //getSpringBean class Object from Container
    bobj=(ModelBean)bfact.getBean("mb");
 }
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    //readFormData
     String city=request.getParameter("city");
     //Call Bmethod
     List l=bobj.searchStudents(city);
     request.setAttribute("attr1",l);
     //Forward the request to resultPage
     RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
     rd.forward(request,response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    doGet(request, response);
}
public void destroy()
{
    bobj=null;
}

}
```

3)ModelBean

```
public class ModelBean implements Model
{
 ModelDao mdao;
 public void setMdao(ModelDao mdao) 
 {
    this.mdao = mdao;
 }

 public ModelDao getMdao() 
 {
    return mdao;
 }

 @Override
 public List searchStudents(String city) 
 {
    //blogic
            if(city==null||city.equals(""))
            {
                city="Hyderabad";
            }
                //use persistance Logic of Dao class.
            List l=mdao.getDetails(city);
          return l;
 }


}
```

4)ModelDao:

```
public class ModelDao 
{
 JdbcTemplate jt;

 public JdbcTemplate getJt() 
 {
    return jt;
 }

 public void setJt(JdbcTemplate jt) 
 {
    this.jt = jt;
 }
 public List getDetails(String city)
 {
    List l=jt.queryForList("Select * from StudentSpringDao where saddress=?",new Object[]{city});
    return l;

 }


}
```

5)ModelCfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  
   <bean id="bds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JalajSchema"/>
   <property name="username" value="root"/>
   <property name="password" value=""/>
   <!--  <property name="MaxActive" value="15"/>
   <property name="MaxIdle" value="5"/>
   <property name="MaxWait" value="5000"/>-->
    </bean>
<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
<property name="dataSource" ref="bds"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mydao" class="ModelDao">
<property name="jt" ref="template"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mb" class="ModelBean">
<property name="mdao" ref="mydao"/>
</bean>
```

6)result.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%
 List l=(List)request.getAttribute("attr1");
 %>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <th>Sno</th>
 <th>Sname</th>
 <th>Saddress</th>
 </tr>
 <%
 for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++)
 {
 Map m=(Map)l.get(i);   %>
 <tr>
 <td><%=m.get("sno") %></td>
 <td><%=m.get("sname") %></td>
 <td><%=m.get("saddress") %></td>
 </tr>
 <%
 }
 %>
```

JarFiles Added:

```
commons-logging-1.2.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar

spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-aspects-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-context-support-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-instrument-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-jdbc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-jms-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-oxm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-struts-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-test-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar

spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Maybe a problem of compatibility between application server ( seems Tomcat) and the jdk. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243458/tomcat7-not-compiling-jsp-examples)