# FAIL - Deployed application at context path / but context failed to start

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

Im working in 2 separate webapplications a back and front app.
The funny thing is when I run the back-end I don't have any issues. But in the front-end  I get the following error:

```
I have the following error in Netbeans 

NetBeans: Deploying on Apache Tomcat or TomEE
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/
OK - Undeployed application at context path /
In-place deployment at D:\WebDevel\WebStore\WebFrontE\target\Web-1.0-SNAPSHOT
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext7815575477480252472.xml&path=/
FAIL - Deployed application at context path / but context failed to start
```

Both are running on the same Tomcat. my colleague has the same code and it works fine :-s

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using?  Are you using a war overlay?

Comment: Is this problem solved yet? Because I get this error after a while of developing. Still don't know the root cause of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Context Path` (or) `Context Root` must be unique for each application deployed on the server.

So you can't deploy two applications with same context root to the same server. It seems for both of your applications the context path is `/`.

Check `server.xml` to see what context path both of them have. If they are not unique, then change them to solve the problem.

But if you want the same context root for both applications, then you need to deploy them in two different servers.

For more information:
[Tomcat Context paths configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)

Comment: Can you please clarify a little more I am facing same issue in netbeans, I added Struts 2 plugin in netbeans 8.2 and created a project using the same but when i try to run the project it seems The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Answer (score 3):

While trying to deploy a spring boot web app from jenkins to an external VM I was getting the same error as below. 
After I look into tomcat log I found it was for java version error. I didnt install proper java version which my spring boot application supports. 
I installed openjdk 8 and removed java7 from vm and it was resolved.

The actual cause behind the below error can be many . so check your tomcat /logs/catalina.out directory for exact error. at Jenkins build log it doesn't give actual error.

FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/webapp] but context

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jsKGhXmm4c

Answer (score 2):

I may be a little late but would say that this could be because of the change in the factory name in Tomcat 8. So follow the below steps:

1) First, see if you are using Tomcat 8 or higher.

2) If yes, and tomcat is not able to deploy your application. Run the application in Debug mode and see stack trace in Tomcat window (at bottom. Not same as Tomcat.log). Scroll down the window and see if you can find an Exception like this:
    ***Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory***

3) If you see something like above, Open your META-INF/context.xml and replace or add the factory attribute in the resource tag with:
factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"

4) Restart tomcat and redeploy.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a d after a lot of links that didn't work, found this solution. Edit the server.xml on your Tomee server to provide a fully qualified path for appBase:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="C:\apache\apache-tomee-7.0.2-plume\webapps"
                  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

The following error occurs if your context has not started well.
Instance : You have context listener that calls a method and the method is not present.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was a syntax error in web.xml, I didn't close an  element

The tomcat window (NetBeans) had a clear errormessage, thanks Arafat

> 01-Sep-2018 17:34:38.641 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.fatalError Parse Fatal Error at line 50 column 11: The element type "param-value" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

Answer (score 1):

I am also had trouble solving this kind of issue on my netbeans. I'm stack the whole day getting rid of this issue. Many solutions have been tried but still nothing happen until I tried to delete the "target" folder of my project and that solved the problem! Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have came across this problems several times,i tried the below steps and it worked..!

**1.** **Backup you current project**(For safety).

**2.** Locate you project folder location (Normally found in **MyDocuments** or **Documents** folder named as **NetBeansProjects**).

**3.** Open the project folder and **delete** the folder named **target** inside your project folder

**4.** Close the NetBeans and re-open the it and run the project.

And you are good to go.

If the above didn't work then try deleting the **xml file** from the folder "**Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost**" folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error while using Java Web due to a syntax error:

My Servlet code should be like this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "EleicaoServlet", urlPatterns = {"/EleicaoServlet", "/main", "/insert", "/edit", "/delete", "/update"})
```

But I forgot to type '/' in the "/update"

```
@WebServlet(name = "EleicaoServlet", urlPatterns = {"/EleicaoServlet", "/main", "/insert", "/edit", "/delete", "update"})
```

And I got this error.

So if nothing above works you may want to check your code, it can be something stupid like this.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried

> mvn clean install

and worked for me for the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

'undeployed application at context path' this error occur due to missing some file while copying project from one system to another.
while coping make sure all files should be copied.If an error occur then please recopy project and import it..
It may work..

Comment: I had this problem. I uploaded the project, but the build was slow and it was not complete yet. This messes up Tomcat, as after copying the files properly the next time, I still can't deploy the webapplication (but the webapplication is not listed in the manager GUI). I probably need to restart Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue i solved by giving security permission to the user for Apache Server Foundation in root folder

Answer (score 0):

in my case i removed some configuration tags that i added in web.xml,trying to configure a strut package.I also removed that package respectively,i restarted the server,run the project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem @ one time. In one of the instance, it was caused by a controller that had multiple methods with same route e.g

```
@RestController
public class UsersController
{   
    @Autowired
    UsersInterface userInterface;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test()
    {
        return "Users";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<user> getUsers()
    {
        List<User> users = userInterface.getUsers();
        return users;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the controller has 2 methods that define two get routes, hence Spring cannot resolve the method to run the `.../users/get` route.

Remote one of the `get` routes and change it to something else.

I may be late to answer but might help others later in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This could be many causes, but the most frequent personally in my case was the web.xml file servlet declarations. When I was cross developing a project both on Mac and Linux, I saw the file behave different in the two platforms due to some space or new line issues. It took me hours to find out as the servlet count was more than 20. Ultimately I narrowed down to strangely only one controller class declaration and found the syntax to be absolutely perfect. It bamboozled me, so I thought I'd rewrite the declaration after deleting the old one and BAM! It worked on Mac immediately. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this problem, after trying several other suggestions, the following thing worked perfectly for me.

Delete the following file:

```
/apache-tomcat-9.0.13/conf/Catalina/localhost/*.xml
```

Comment: It's empty for me and there are no `.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but for anyone who might face the same error.

For me, this error was caused by wrong syntax in my servlet.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/x/login", "/x/register", "/x/logout", "x/createrestaurant"})
```

It looked like the above and I got the same error. After sometime and trying to deploy on a different server (from Tomcat to Glassfish), Glassfish gave me better logs and I realized the syntax should have been like this

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/x/login", "/x/register", "/x/logout", "/x/createrestaurant"}).
```

Notice the `/` before x/createrestaurant.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with even newly added projects tried a lot of stuff mentioned above. what works for me is to manually Stop tomcat service in the Installation directory  \Tomcat 9.0\bin Tomcat9w.exe. Then deployed the project it works this way in Netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 0):

FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path...

I was facing the same issue. But I resolved it. Please see the following steps:

1. First, stop the Tomcat service that is already running on the background, Not in the Netbeans. For this, go to TaskManager properties>Services>tomcat
2. Right click on the tomcat service to stop
3. Now, after that. Close netbeans IDE and run again
4. Right click on the project and select run. The project will be running without any issue

I hope above solution will be helpfull who having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

One Problem could be the port you are trying to use might be being used by another application. Try changing the port or clearing that one and it might work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been resolved by stopping the Tomcat server
`sudo systemctl stop tomcat`
so as to allow Netbeans to run it. If the server is already running when Netbeans tries to deploy an app Netbeans will display the delopy failed message.

Answer (score 0):

After Installing tomcat do not start the service. Netbeans starts tomcat a different way. for me i have uninstall tomcat and installed it again.

1. Uninstall tomcat and install it. dont run the server.
2. Add tomcat server in netbeans.
3. run it again it works.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but I used only maven (without IDE). My tomcat version was tomcat7 7.0.70-1 and jdk8 (in `pom.xml`: `<java.version>1.8</java.version>`) It turned out that tomcat7 [incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294355/is-tomcat-7-now-compatible-with-java-7/9294694#9294694) with java 8, so, I changed `java.version` in `pom.xml` on `<java.version>1.7</java.version>` and that was the solution!

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem and I resolved this issue by stopping the tomcat from IDE and run the web application it starts the tomcat automatically.(This works in Netbeans IDE). Simply Stop Tomcat and start again and redeploy web application.