# Java code compiled using an older JDK will not work properly with a newer JRE/JVM

Tags: java, eclipse

Since this became long and rather specific, I thought that it might be a good idea to insert a few lines to clarify the question and why this may be useful for others.  Please keep in mind this is my first question.  If I have included too little or too much information, please let me know.

The question that I would like to ask is:

Are there portions of Java that will cease to work as expected across the various versions of Java due to library code changes or security patches?  Can it be determined if this is the case with my issue?

I believe that this information will be helpful to other programming novices by helping them to better understand the changes that take place when the Java language evolves to its newer versions.  I have found a question on this site that goes over the changes to the versions of java from 1.5 to versions 1.6 and 1.7 ([New features in JDK 1.6 and 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784158/new-features-in-jdk-1-6-and-1-7)) but I have not been able to identify a reason that my code is not working properly.

I have written a program that can retrieve values from a Windows system using a Runtime object to execute command line requests.  The information that is retrieve are mainly registry key values.  After retrieving this information, I have the program create a File object and output the retrieved information to an HTML file that it creates.  I can create and run an executable JAR file on each of the respective versions (1.5 and 1.7).  When executing the 1.5 JAR on a 1.7 system however, the resulting HTML is created but remains blank.  Another portion of the program that stops working is its debug option.  I created a debug option that looks for a file called debug.txt in the same directory that the JAR is located.  The 1.5 version does not activate the debug option on 1.7 though.

*EDIT*

Summary of issue:

My program should be creating an HTML file from the information that it retrieves from the system.  At this time, when the 1.5 compiled version is run with java version 1.7, it simply creates a blank HTML file rather than one filled with information.  Another change is that the program usually generates a debug log file with the string created as seen in the first code segments catch block.  This should be done when the file debug.txt exists, but does not.

*EDIT*

I researched the issue and know that Java is intended to be backwards compatible.  I have not been able to locate any issue that might point to a version issue.  I believe that I likely have something that is wrong with my code when applied across versions.

I have included some code to the sections that are not working as expected.

```
try{
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\Desktop\\Results.html");

    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(file);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);

    out.println("A large" + amount + "of concatenated" + strings);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}catch(IOException e){
    //debugErrorString currently has global scope
    debugErrorString += ("*************************************************************\r\n" + 
                                "There was an issue with writting the results.html document" + e + 
                                "\r\n**********************************************************\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n");
}
```

```
public static void writeDebugLog(){
    try{
        final String debugLogFile = "C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + 
                                                "\\Documents\\WorkstationDebugLogFile.txt";

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(debugLogFile));

        //registry currently has global scope
        out.println(debugErrorString + "\n\n\n" + registry.getDebugString() + "\r\n");
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Additional information:

1. This code was written, codded, compiled, and packaged into a JAR file using Eclipse
2. Testing was performed on two Windows 7 x64 systems
3. I realize that creating code specific to an operating system is against the goal of
   Java.

   - The application that this program retrieves information for will only utilize 
     Windows operating systems.
   - I also require information from the Windows registry.  Not sure how I would do this 
     and maintain Javas cross platform functionality.
4. I allowed Eclipse to generate the manifest file automatically
5. I am relatively new to creating Java programs.  I will greatly appreciate any comments
   that help me address any issues with my coding or question writing for this site.

Thank you for taking the time to review this information and my question.

*EDIT*

Additional information gained from suggestions.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
    Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:-1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1958)
    at com.McKesson.WorkstationDiagnostic.WorkstationDiagnostic.createPage(WorkstationDiagnostic.java:321)
    at com.McKesson.WorkstationDiagnostic.WorkstationDiagnostic.main(WorkstationDiagnostic.java:125)
    ... 5 more
```

The line in question is:

```
if(new File(envVar.substring(envVar.indexOf("C:\\oracle\\product\\"), envVar.indexOf("\\bin;C:\\") + 4)).exists())
```

While I am not certain why the sub string is not found only when crossing versions, I now have something to look at.  I will have to deal with this sub string not being found and exceeding the limits of the searched string, as well as determining why this issue has ocured when crossing versions.

This leads me back to the original question as well.  Why would something like this not work only when executing with a newer version?

*EDIT*

*EDIT*

Based on the comments, I have made the following changes:

```
if(new File(envVar.substring(envVar.indexOf("C:\\oracle\\product\\"), envVar.indexOf("\\bin;C:\\") + 4)).exists())
```

has been changed to

```
String tokens [] = envVar.split(";");

    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        if(tokens[i].contains("C:\\Oracle\\Product") && new File(tokens[i]).exists())
```

This should also remove the possibility of throwing the array index error that was seen.  I am also thinking that the second test will not be performed if the first test is false.

The goal that I was attempting to reach with this line was to determine that the environmental variables contained an actual location of the Oracle bin directory.

If there are any suggestions to improve upon my resolution, please let me know.

*EDIT*

Comment: Better exception handling will help you figure out what's going on. Rather than `catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);  }`, try `catch(Exception e){ throw new RuntimeException(e) }`. Run your program from a command prompt window, and you'll see any stack trace printed

Comment: You failed to tell us what this code is supposed to do, and what it does instead. All we know is that it's "not working as expected". which doesn't tell us much about the actual problem you face.

Comment: Thank you for the comments so far.
@artbristol I will be adjusting this in the future to reflect more information for debugging thank you for the suggestion.  This program does not report any errors at this time however.  I am unsure why it is not performing as expected.

Comment: @JBNizet I am sorry that I was unclear on what this program does.  I have added the line "The information that is retrieve are mainly registry key values".  I am unsure what else to add about the program.  I have stated that it should create an html file about the information retrieved but only creates a blank file.

Comment: Well, that's probably because you catch the IOException that is thrown, but ignore it. As indicated by the first comment, replace the body of your catch block by `throw new RuntimeException(e)`. Also, use a debugger to know what your code does.

Comment: Just a hint that may or may not help you. So, give it a try. There are some issues with running eclipse on Windows 7 regarding writing files (JRE version independant). You need specific permissions to do that. So, try to run your eclipse  with administrator rights.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I was able to get a reported error by doing this.  I am including the stack trace in the question.  I will now have to determine why the issue is only occurring when the different versions are used.

Comment: @JorgeCampos  Thank you for making me aware of the Eclipse/Windows 7 issue.  I attempted to resolve my issue with this suggestion to no avail.  I will be adjusting this applications properties to run correctly from now on though.

Comment: This line of yours `if(new File(envVar.substring(envVar.indexOf("C:\\oracle\\product\\"), envVar.indexOf("\\bin;C:\\") + 4)).exists())` is a bit messy because if you have another program with the folder `\\bin` before the `"C:\\oracle\\product\\"` it could cause the problem. So my suggestion is to split the envvars by `;` then find what you need.

Comment: The problem is probably not caused by a change in the versin of Java, but by a change in what the environment variable that your code manipulates contains. 99.99999% of the time, when you have a bug, it's caused by your code, not by the JDK.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thank you for the suggestion, and I believe that I will implement it.  I just want to make sure that I understand completely.  This could cause issues because the second envVar.indexOf will search from the start of the string and could result in a lower index value than the starting index value.

Comment: Exactly this. In order help you better: Open cmd, run `echo %path%` then paste it to your question and say what you want to extract from that.

Comment: @JBNizet While this seems to hold true, I do not understand why this worked when turned into a JAR and run on the same version, but not when run on different versions.  This error that I have seen would point to there being an issue with the coding, but was only reported when the 1.5 version was run on a 1.7 version.

Comment: Use a debugger, or even trace statements, to know what value the envVar has in each version.

Comment: Thats is very simple. In the older version (jdk 1.5) the path for the JDK is in wrong place regarding the oracle path. Like: in jdk 1.5 your path variable is: `%systemroot%;c:\blah;C:\oracle\product\;c:\jdk15\bin` and in the new one (jdk17) the path is like: `%systemroot%;c:\blah;c:\jdk17\bin;C:\oracle\product\;`

Comment: @JorgeCampos That make sense.  I almost feel stupid for not thinking of it.  Nice catch.

Comment: There were a lot of useful comments that helped me to resolve my issue.  I believe there is a lot of useful information on ensuring that the proper catching is performed and Javas backwards functionality.  Should I summarize an answer myself based on this information?

Comment: At this time, I cannot answer my own question due to how recent I posted the question and my low reputation (below 10).  I will post my response when I am allowed to do so.

That time will be after 11/12/2013 12:32:22 AM

Comment: I have posted the solution that I applied to my program within my question.  Thank you all for your assistance with my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is strongly backwards compatible.  When an issue does arise, it is likely due to a bug in the created code.  In the recent past, there were issues with older Applets due to stronger security measures.  If you are experiencing issues with your code, you should ensure that you are utilizing proper debugging techniques, before reaching the conclusion of Java version issues.

For This particular issue, there was a bug with the way that the environmental variable was being read.  By searching for a sub string ending with "\bin" there was the possibility of reaching this common string prior to the starting string of "C:\oracle\product\".  This would throw an error since the end of the requested sub string would be before the start.  The reason that this resulted in the behavior seen would be due to the placement of the JDK 1.5 within the environmental variable.

This issue was also missed due to improper debugging practices.  While an IDE (Eclipse in this case) is useful for writing and debugging code, it is often the case that more useful information can be retrieved from running programs from the command line.  In this example, the program executed properly when run from within Eclipse, but not as a JAR.  Therefore, there was no System output to be reviewed when the JAR was executed with a double clicked.  Running the JAR with the use of a command prompt allowed for the errors to have a visible space to be reviewed in.

Answer (score 0):

As there so many comments:

One thing worth checking: **compile the application with both Java versions**. Then you can check with Java 7 runtime whether there *is* a difference.

In general:

1. Java indeed is strongly backwards compatible.

1a. However: old Applets not long ago get problems due to stronger security measures.

1. Seeing the code I doubt a Java version incompatibility is involved. Still...

Comment: My issue is now resolved, and all useful information was provided in the form of comments.  This information is also useful, but does not cover the information provided in the comments in its entirety. I would like to mark an answer for my question, but I think it should contain more information than what is provided here.  Should I propose a solution, or should I wait for another individual to write a good answer?

Comment: You may invite one of the commenters to turn its comment into an answer, but I think you may formulate the answer better. Make your own answer and accept it afterwards; that is fine.