# Digit Separator in Julia

Tags: python, c++, integer, julia, separator

Coding in Julia shows that using underscore as integer digit separator works in Julia.

```
x = 1_000_000
```

and

```
   x = 1000000
```

are basically the same thing.

However, I am not able to locate the documentation for this, to read more details. Could anyone point me to that.

Also is digit separation character a common thing in different languages? What are the separator character in C++, java, and Python?

Comment: I don't think python has one? I've always just done things like `10**6`

Comment: @deviantfan Actually C++14 introduced ' as digit separator I believe.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks, didn´t know that before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [standards proposal document for C++14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3499.html) has a very lengthy discussion on the rationale and possible choices for a digit separator.  The considered `` ` ``, `'`, `_`, `::`, and  (space).  Some of the discussion cites other languages.  According to the document, `_` is also used in Ada, VHDL, Verilog, and possibly Algol68.  Underscores also appear to be used in Java 7 ([StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212558/java-7-underscore-in-numeric-literals), [proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-April/001628.html)).  C++ settled on `'` as their separator.

Julia hasn't formally documented underscore-separated numeric literals yet, but you can find some information in [this GitHub issue (#848)](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/848) and [this julia-dev thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/julia-dev/bRPc_c0dFdQ/kOqUTGXKii0J).

It doesn't look like Python has a numeric literal separator.

Comment: `_` is also used in [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors).

Comment: Note: Algol68 sidestepped the entire issue by allowing a space in a number, for example: 1 million could be 1 000 000, and π could be 3.14159 26535 89793 23846 ...

Answer (score 3):

I've just made a pull request to add this to the manual, when you spot things missing it's very easy to add them to the documentation, see:

- [Improving documentation](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#improving-documentation)
- [Add reference to `_` as digit separator. #12253](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/12253)