# Are there binary literals in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, binary, literals

I want to declare my integer number by a binary literal. Is it possible in Java?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Starting with Java 7 you can represent integer numbers directly **as binary numbers**, using the form `0b` (or `0B`) followed by one or more binary digits (0 or 1). For example, `0b101010` is the integer 42. Like octal and hex numbers, binary literals may represent negative numbers.

If you do not have Java 7 use this:

```
int val = Integer.parseInt("001101", 2);
```

There are other ways to enter integer numbers:

1. As decimal numbers such as `1995`, `51966`. Negative decimal numbers such as `-42` are actually expressions consisting of the integer literal with the unary negation operation.
2. As octal numbers, using a leading 0 (zero) digit and one or more additional octal digits (digits between 0 and 7), such as 077. Octal numbers may evaluate to negative numbers; for example `037777777770` is actually the decimal value -8.
3. As hexadecimal numbers, using the form 0x (or 0X) followed by one or more hexadecimal digits (digits from 0 to 9, a to f or A to F). For example, `0xCAFEBABEL` is the long integer 3405691582. Like octal numbers, hexadecimal literals may represent negative numbers.

More details can be found [in this Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Literals/Numeric_Literals/Integer_Literals).

Comment: +1 you can `double` literals in hexi-decmal. See the source for `Double` for examples.

Answer (score 47):

In JDK 7 it is possible:

```
int binaryInt = 0b101;
```

Just prefix your number with `0b`.

Comment: Got an exercise problem using this syntax and just found out about it. See also [chapter 3.10.1 in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-BinaryNumeral) for the exact syntax and some examples.