# Best approach for try/catch while dealing with jdbc connection

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to find out what is the best approach for try/catch when dealing with connections in JDBC.

My personal view is.

```
Connection conn = null;
try{
    conn = getDBConnection(); 
    //Some jdbc code
} catch(SQLException e) {
    //...
} finally {
    if(conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

But I have seen few smart guys doing this

```
Connection conn = null;
try{
    conn = getDBConnection(); 
    //Some jdbc code
    conn.close();
    conn = null;
} catch(SQLException e) {
    //...
} finally {
    if(conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any advantage in closing the connection in try and setting it to null?

Comment: Your approach is better, also, if you're using java 7, see my answer on try-catch [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739362/java7-try-with-resources-statement-advantage/17739460#17739460)

Comment: morgano thanks for pointing this out I am aware of Java 7's cool feature however we are still using JDK6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your smart guys are not that smart. Your approach is the way to go. Close the connection only once in your `finally` block, and there's no reason to set the connection to `null`, that's what automatic garbage collection is for.

Comment: I think the smart guys were worried about the fact that, if they don't set `conn` to null, condition check in the finally might succeed cause a exception since the connection is already closed.  Thanks!!