# BufferedReader not reading complete .txt file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a moderately sized txt file (65,00 words) into a String, then a string array.  The bufferedreader throws the "could not read file" catch.  When I clear it, a small part of the contents of the text file is shown in the system.out.  I do not get the error with smaller text files. I'm a beginner and I'm having a lot of trouble trying to narrow down the issue.

Why isn't the BufferedReader ingesting the entire file?  And why is the "could not read file" error being thrown?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Guid Main = new Guid();  //creates instance of Guid

    Main.mergeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
        merge();

        }
    });

}
    static void merge()
    {

        //read file and turn into string
        String pathone = open(Guid.PathOne);
        System.out.print(pathone);

        //parse and format 
        //String[] oneArray = pathone.replace("\n"," ").split(" "); 


        //get pathtwo text
        //String pathtwo = open(Guid.PathTwo);

        //parse and format
        //load into array
        //compare array entries
        //add new array entry
        //sort array
        //write array to paththree file


        //for(int i=0; i<oneArray.length;i++)
        //{
            //System.out.println(oneArray[i]);
        //}

    }


    public static String open(JTextArea Path)
    {
        String record = null;

        FileReader frFile = null;
        try {
            frFile = new FileReader(Path.getText());//gets file from Path

            BufferedReader brFile = new BufferedReader(frFile);//creates buffered reader

            record = brFile.readLine() + "\n"; //gets contents of file and puts it into a string
            brFile.mark(0);

            while (brFile.read() != -1) //loop to read the rest of the text file
                {
                    brFile.reset();
                    record = record + brFile.readLine() + "\n";
                    brFile.mark(0);
                }

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) //catch path is in error
            {
                JFrame frame = null;

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Could not find file.");
            } 
        catch (IOException e) //catch if file cannot be read
            {
                JFrame frame = null;

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Could not read file.");
            }

        try {  //closes file
            frFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return record;
    }


}
```

Comment: For starters, we need the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do in this way. Remove `reset()` and `mark()` methods if you want to read the entire file.

```
StringBuilder record = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader brFile = new BufferedReader(frFile);
String line = null;
while ((line = brFile.readLine()) != null) {
    record.append(line).append("\n");
}
```

---

#### Note:

- Don't forget to close the stream.
- Use finally block to close the stream
- Use StringBuilder or StringBuffer to append the string.
- Use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to get the system specific line separator

Have a look at [Java7 try-with-resources Statement advantage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739362/java7-try-with-resources-statement-advantage)

Answer (score 1):

readLine will read the first line of your document.
Try with it (not tested):

```
String lineReaded;

while ((lineReaded=brFile.readLine())!=null) 
{
record +=linereaded+"\n";
}
```

Niko

Answer (score 1):

You might like to use [Files.readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)