# run things in parallel with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to run plugins in parallel, I'm trying with multithreading but I have no idea on
how to close the thread when the task is gone, or do I even need to close it ?
Since it's a program just run, display something and end almost immediatly, so if there are some unused threads in the background it don't change much i guess ?

Here is how it look right now, does it look good ?

```
ArrayList<Thread> listOfThreads = new ArrayList<>();

pluginsList.forEach( ( plugin ) -> {
        Thread thread = new Thread( () -> plugin.run() );
        thread.start();
        listOfThreads.add( thread );
} );
// closing all threads
listOfThreads.forEach( ( thread ) -> thread.stop() );
```

Comment: you might want to `join` on the threads, rather than `stop` them, otherwise not much is going to happen

Comment: You probably want to use an `ExecutorService` and deal with `Future`s, rather than deal with threads directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to clean up Thread objects in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299070/do-i-need-to-clean-up-thread-objects-in-java)

Comment: Thread.stop() is deprecated in new versions of java. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504140/thread-stop-deprecated. Aviod using it.

Comment: you need not to clean a thread, it cleans itself just after finishes its work.