# spring try catch vs try(statement) catch - spring

Tags: java, spring

I wanted to know the difference (if any) between **try(statement?){} catch()** and **try{} catch()**, that I saw applied in Spring, and if I'm also correct in .net. I have tried both but have not seen any difference. Is it for performance or just a choice?

**example**:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build()) {
 log.warn("closeable call");
 // some logic 
}
catch (exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

```
try {
 // some logic 
} catch (exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: These aren't equivalent code blocks, so your question makes no sense.  In the first block, `httpClient.close()` will be called when the code exits the `try/catch` block.  That's the whole point of `try(statement)`. - as the documentation referenced above describes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17739362/217324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to mention two things before answering your question.

1. try(statement) is not a spring feature. It is feature of Java which is introduced in Java-7.
2. try(statements) is called as ***try with resources***.

**About try(statements):**
Statement'(s) inside try can be any class or interface reference which directly or indirectly implement/extend **AutoCloseable** interface in java. (**AutoCloseable** interface have abstract method close()). Means you no need to call close() method explicitly for your resources. If you don't use try with resources programmer have to call close() method for opened resources explicitly.

For more detail read about ***try with resources*** in java.