# Get the value from the file in Java

Tags: java, file

How do I fetch a value corresponding to i (if i=5, I must get 57.05698808926067) from a text file `myFile.txt` ? The values may continue till 25000.

```
0->37.6715587270802
1->40.02056806304368
2->351.65161070935005
3->54.74486689415533
4->86.12063488461266
5->57.05698808926067
6->0.0
7->56.078343612293374
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: can  you post your program code ??

Comment: If the the file was like `0=37.6715587270802` it was ideal candidate for Properties file :)

Comment: @Subir Kumar Sao : property file with 25K of lines will be inefficient to handle just for one line

Comment: You can also create Hashmap after reading the values from file and split("->"). Let the key be 0,1,...,25000 and value be the corresponding one.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
// Note: bounds checking left as an exercise
public double getDoubleFromFile(final String filename, final int index)
    throws IOException
{
    final List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(paths.get(filename),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    return Double.parseDouble(list.get(index));
}
```

However, this slurps the whole file. Why not, if you have to query several times. Another solution:

```
public double getDoubleFromFile(final String filename, final int index)
    throws IOException
{
    final Path path = Paths.get(filename);
    int i = 0;
    String line;
    try (
        final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ) {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (index == i)
                return Double.parseDouble(line);
            i++;
        }
        return Double.NaN;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line and check characters before `"->"` and parse them to int and compare with `i`. Then get the values after `"->"`.

You could also just read line by line and increment the value of an index variable every time you read a line and when the index is equal to `i`, get the string after `"->"`.

Answer (score 0):

This simple way is to read line by line til you get to your line

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
int i=0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   if (i == muLineNumber){
       // process the line. 
       break;
   }

   i++;
}
br.close();
```

If the size of each line const, you can use [BufferedReader.skip](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedreader_skip.htm)

If the file size of small, use [FileUtils.readLines](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29)

Choose what is best for you

Comment: `FileUtils.readLines()` is basically superseded by Java 7's `Files.readAllLines()`

Comment: Heh, Java 8 is out today (Thu Mar 18th) and people still don't use the new Java 7 file API ;) It is miles better than `File`.

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/working-with-files-java-6-versus-java-7.html), in the hope you will find it useful

Comment: java 7 highlight : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213958/new-features-in-java-7

Answer (score 0):

Since 25'000 lines is not that huge, I would load the whole file in an array, and use i as an index into the array. If, however, I had harsh constraints on memory usage, I would use an RandomAccessFile, set position somewhere around i*average-line-length, find the next '\n', then read the index, if the index is the one that I was seeking, I would read the rest of the line, otherwise, move up if the index is greater or down if it's smaller, and repeat the process.